# Make 1 table look like 2 on top of each other

Tags: html, css

[image]I want to make 1 table to look like 2 tables where they are on top of each other with a little space between them. Each table has the same number of columns, but the text they contain can differ. And each table can contain many rows. I need this because i need columns of both tables always to be the same width. How do i achieve this? I need that Empty row's side borders to hide

```
<table>
  <tr> <!-- First table rows --> </tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>

  <tr> <!-- Empty space between tables --> </tr>

  <tr> <!-- Second table rows --> </tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
```

Comment: please  share some code of what you have did ? or share image of what you r trying to achieve .

Comment: i did add a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a single `<td>` element with a specific height as a separator, and use `border-collapse` to mimic what you're looking for:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

table td.separator {
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="separator"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for this. **border-spacing**

Change 45px for sizing

```css
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
} 
th { 
    background-color: red; 
    Color:white; 
} 
th, td { 
    width:150px; 
    text-align:center; 
    border:1px solid black; 
    padding:5px 

} 
.geeks { 
    border-right:hidden; 
} 
.gfg { 
    border-collapse:separate; 
    border-spacing:0 45px; 
} 
h1 { 
    color:green; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <style> 
             
        </style> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <center> 
        <h2>Row spacing in a table</h2> 
        <table> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Employee ID</th> 
                <th>Name</th> 
                <th>Gender</th> 
                <th>Age</th> 
            </tr> 
        </table> 
        <table class = "gfg"> 
            <tr> 
                <td class = "geeks">10001</td> 
                <td>Thomas</td> 
                <td>M</td> 
                <td>32</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td class = "geeks">10002</td> 
                <td>Sally</td> 
                <td>F</td> 
                <td>28</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td class = "geeks">10003</td> 
                <td>Anthony</td> 
                <td>M</td> 
                <td>24</td> 
            </tr> 
        </table> 
        </center> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like shown below. The `colspan="4"` on `table-spacing td` specifies how many columns the cell should span.

**Advice**

However if the data is really different from each other I would recommend actually using two different tables instead of two . It make it easier for screen readers to distinct the data from each other. To improve this further you can use table headers to improve your accessibility even more.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-spacing td {
  border: none;
  height: 15px; /* Increase/descrease for white-space between 'tables' */
}

td {
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td> Cel 1</td>
    <td> Cel 2</td>
    <td> Cel 3</td>
    <td> Cel 4</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Cel 5</td>
    <td> Cel 6</td>
    <td> Cel 7</td>
    <td> Cel 8</td>
  <tr>
  <tr class="table-spacing"><td colspan="4"></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Cel 1</td>
    <td> Cel 2</td>
    <td> Cel 3</td>
    <td> Cel 4</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Cel 5</td>
    <td> Cel 6</td>
    <td> Cel 7</td>
    <td> Cel 8</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```